# Configuration of Orthanc Server on Synology with Docker getting issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, synology, nas, orthanc-server

My configuration inside `docker-compose.yml` with Orthanc is

```py
      orthanc-42:
        image: jodogne/orthanc-plugins
        ports:
          - '4242:4242'
          - '8042:8042'
      volumes:
        # Config
        - ./config/42/orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json:ro
        - ./config/42/transcodeAndForward.lua:/etc/share/orthanc/scripts/transcodeAndForward.lua
        - ./config/42/countSearch.py:/etc/share/orthanc/scripts/countSearch.py
        # Here i have mount My Synology storage path
        - /mnt/win_share/Jarry/test/46/:/var/lib/orthanc/db/'
```

I get this error while running docker-compose up:

```
nginx-orthanc_orthanc-42_1 exited with code 255
```

Comment: can anyone help me with this issue , maybe i have need to change my othanc.json file

Comment: geting issue inside terminal  SQLite execute error: no such table: main.Cache (1)